Managing wrong order of strings in R and ggplot. X1, X10, X12: How can I ensure a string with number will be preented in the right numberical order?
Every time that I want to plot or list a string that contains numbers, R (and python) list the values such as "x1, x10, x11, x13, (etc) x2, x3, x4"

I tried to solve this using gtools::mixedsort(variable) but for some reason beyond my knowledge and patience it's not working.
Could someone give me a heads up on how to solve this? Code is below:
library(tidyverse)
df = data.frame(data.frame(x = 1:3))
for (i in 1:15) {
  df[ , paste0("asq_", i)]   <- c(0,5,10)
}

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-x,names_to = "asq_item", values_to = "response")%>% 
  group_by(asq_item, response) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  group_by(asq_item) %>%
  mutate(proportion = count / sum(count)) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = asq_item, y = proportion, fill = factor(response)))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",  position=position_dodge2(width = 0.9, preserve = "single")) +
  labs(title = "Prevalence of Each Category Within Each ASQ Item",
       x = "ASQ Item",
       y = "Count",
       fill = "Response") +
  theme_bw() 


Created on 2024-07-23 with reprex v2.1.0

Well, you were on the right track, but you didn't show the code you tried. You can do this by converting the variable to a factor, with the levels specified as the unique sorted values.
library(gtools)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-x, names_to = "asq_item", values_to = "response") %>% 
  mutate(asq_item=factor(asq_item, levels=mixedsort(unique(asq_item)))) %>%
  group_by(asq_item, response) %>%
...

gives you


You´re again helping me. Thanks a lot!
